# conditionally bind angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am 100% new to AngularJS, and I am trying to set a condition for displaying a String. If the text the user enters starts with the letter `a`, it should display `Hello {{name}}, welcome back!` (where `{{name}}` binds to the name entered), otherwise the text should not appear. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <title>Type Your Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Please type your name:
        <br />
        <table><input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        </br>
        Hello {{name}}, welcome back!

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js">
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did my answer not solve your problem? I'd appreciate if you'd mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, and sorry for the delayed reply. Your answer solved my problem 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `ng-if` and check if the first character is the letter a.

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
    <span ng-if="name.charAt(0) === 'a'">Hello {{name}}, welcome back!</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyw64yzg/).

Do not use `ng-show` because it *always* renders the DOM element and hides it if conditions are not met, `ng-if` renders the DOM element if and *only if* the condition is met.

Comment: I see plenty of other places which suggest using `ng-show` for this.  This answer needs more attention!